# Nested class won't read from mother class

Tags: java, event-handling

I'm beginning to learn GUI Java and I have a "NewClass" class that holds a window with some fields and a button, I have nested a "Escuchador" class inside this class to use as an event handler but it keeps giving me the error "cannot find this symbol". I have made a few tests and it just wont read from inside "NewClass". I don't understand what's wrong, please help, this is the code:

```
package javaapplication1;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class NewClass extends JFrame {
    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200;

    public NewClass() {
        super("ARTICULACION SOCIAL");
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel heading = new JLabel("Identifiquese para entrar");
        heading.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        JLabel namePrompt = new JLabel("Ingrese su nombre de usuario:");
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField(12);
        JLabel namePrompt2 = new JLabel("Ingrese su contraseña:");
        JTextField nameField2 = new JTextField(12);    
        JButton button = new JButton("Ingresar");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(heading);
        add(namePrompt);
        add(nameField);
        add(namePrompt2);
        add(nameField2);
        add(button);

        Escuchador escuchar = new Escuchador();
        nameField.addActionListener(escuchar);
        nameField2.addActionListener(escuchar);
        button.addActionListener(escuchar);

    }

    private class Escuchador implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
            String usuario="";


            if (event.getSource()== nameField) {
               usuario = event.getActionCommand();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: nameField is a local variable of the NameField constructors. Local variables are... local. They're not visible outside of the block where they're defined. You need to make it a field.

Comment: i added the field at the start of the class, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `nameField` is a local variable in your constructor. Its scope is no bigger than your constructor.

You have several options.

Make `nameField` a class variable (define it outside your constructor), so that your inner class will be able to use it.

Alternatively you can pass `nameField` to your inner class as a constructor parameter:

```
public class Escuchador implements ActionListener{

    private JTextField nameField;

    public Escuchador(JTextField nameField){
        this.nameField = nameField;
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
        String usuario = "";

        if (event.getSource()== this.nameField) {
           usuario = event.getActionCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't even need to define this class as an inner class, which by the way is the more preferred way.

Comment: thanks i declared 'namefield' at the begining and that solved it all, thanks a lot

Comment: wait what did you mean with not having to use an inner class? 'Escuchador' is the nested class not the main class so your example would still be nested inside the 'NewClass' wich is the outside class

Comment: I meant, you can extract Escuchador to its own class, in a file named Escuchador.java. Letting 'Escuchador' class not be private will still let you use it in NewClass.
It's a better OOP approach to have seperate classes in seperate files. I was assuming, that you are declaring `Escuchador` as an inner class so that you can reach `nameField` field which is declared in `NewClass`. But if you pass the variable through `Escuchador`'s constructor, and make `nameField` its own class variable, there will be no reason not to extract it to an own class. Hope i was clear, let me know, if i can help you.